# Question about Schur's Lemma

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Maybe a very dumb question about Schur's Lemma, but somehow this confuses me.

Let $G, H$ be groups. A function $f: G\rightarrow H$ is called group isomorphism, if $f(g\cdot h) = f(g)*f(h)$, and $f$ is bijective.

Let $(D_1,V_1)$ and $(D_2,V_2)$ be irreducible representations of a group $G$, and $A \in L(V_1 \rightarrow V_2)$ a linear function. If $A D_1(g) = D_2(g)A \hspace{5mm}  \forall g \in  G$, than A is either the $0-$ map or an isomorphism.

So in the proof of Schur's Lemma, (for example [here](https://www.physik.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Eborghini/Teaching/Symmetries/11_14a.pdf)) it is shown, that A has to be either the $0-$function or bijective. But what is the argument to say that it is an bijective group homomorphism (= group isomorphism)? Do I have a wrong understanding of isomorphism?

Comment: A linear function from $V_1$ to $V_2$ is a homomorphism of the underlying group structure by definition

Comment: It's the fact that $AD_1(g)=D_2(g)A$ that's important. Schur's lemma says that $A$ is an isomorphism of $kG$-modules, or representations, not an isomorphism of groups.

Comment: Well, a linear map between vector spaces (or more generally modules) is indeed a (additive) group homomorphism isn’t it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many types of homomorphisms/isomorphisms in mathematics. Here the meaning is not an isomorphism of groups, but an isomorphism of representations. Given two representations $(V_1,\pi_1), (V_2,\pi_2)$ an isomorphism is an invertible linear map $A:V_1\to V_2$ such that $A(g.v)=g.(Av)$ for all $g\in G, v\in V_1$.

Comment: Doesn't isomorphism mean $A(g\cdot f) = A(g) *A(f)$? So does it mean that in this case $g,f$ are  elements of the vector space (with the binary operation $\cdot \equiv +$) rather than beeing representation (Matrices) with the matrixmultiplication as binary operation?,

Comment: No, this is what I wrote in the answer-$A$ is not a group isomorphism, it is an isomorphism of representations. This is just a different term. It is a function $A:V_1\to V_2$, a map between vector spaces. It has to be bijective, linear and also satisfy the condition $A\circ\pi_1=\pi_2\circ A$. (which is equivalent to what I wrote in the answer). In other words, as a function $A$ is defined on vector spaces, maps elements of $V_1$ to $V_2$.

Comment: Can you give me a reference for this? I have never seen that definition of isomorphism before..

Comment: You can see it even in wikipedia, the definition of equivalent/isomorphic representations. And I believe it appears in pretty much any book about group representations. I'll also add that there are a lot of different isomorphisms in mathematics. Given some objects an isomorphism is usually a bijective function which preserves their structure. There are isomorphisms of groups, vector spaces, representations, modules, graphs, rings, ordered sets and more. So you have to know what type of isomorphism this is. So here we discuss isomorphisms of representations.

Comment: Ok, now that makes sense for me, thank's!